# Scala - How to find the base path of two or more paths?

Tags: scala, path, prefix

Given a sequence of directory paths, what is the best way to find their most common base directory?

Here is the code I wrote.

```
 def commonPrefix(paths: String*): String = {
    paths.reduce((left: String, right: String) => {
      left.split('/')
        .zip(right.split('/'))
        .takeWhile((tuple: (String, String)) => tuple._1.equals(tuple._2))
        .map(_._1).mkString("/")
    })
  }
```

Is there any better way of doing this?

## UPDATE

Following the comments to this question, I have changed the code to address a few issues:

1. Over splitting
2. Empty input
3. Other separators

Ended up with:

```
def commonPrefix(paths: String*)(implicit separator: Char = '/'): String = {
    paths.map(s => s.split(separator))
      .reduceOption((left: Array[String], right: Array[String]) => {
        left
          .zip(right)
          .takeWhile(tuple => tuple._1.equals(tuple._2))
          .map(_._1)
      }).getOrElse(Array[String]())
      .mkString("/")
  }
```

I chose to use `reduceOption` over changing the signature to `commonPrefix(path: String, paths: String*)`, because then I can use the following syntax:

```
val paths = Seq("/a/b", "/a/c")
val baseDir = commonPrefix(paths:_*)
```

Looks OK to me now.

I guess there is no existing Java/Scala library that already does all this, right?

Comment: seems about right ... I would pre-split everything at the beginning, and then operate on a list of lists, and just `.mkString` at the very end. That way, you don't have to re-split, your accumulator at the beginning of every iteration, and re-join it at the end.

Comment: You could add a first argument: `def commonPrefix(path: String, paths: String*)` and then do `(path +: paths).reduce` to ensure that your list will never be empty.

Comment: Why do you need to split by `'/`? why not simply `.toArray`?

Comment: @Dani, Thanks for your comments. I'll update my question shortly. regarding the split, using `.toArray` might lead to non-existent paths. e.g. `"/a/ab"` and `/a/ac` will result in `/a/a` which is not a real path.

Comment: If `separator` (I corrected the spelling) has a default value, why make it implicit as well? That's just asking for trouble.

Comment: @jwvh - Because if I don't the compiler complains that there's a missing argument.

Comment: Then why put it in it's own parameter group? What purpose does that serve?

Comment: @jwvh because, logically, I'd expect it to be last, as a parameter that is rarely used. But `paths` has to be last, because it's a `*` parameter.

Comment: Ah, I see what you're after. I still think making it implicit is dangerous. It could work flawlessly for years, and then someone places an implicit `Char` in scope and, without touching any of your code, `commonPrefix()` starts producing bad results.

Comment: @jwvh, I agree. open for suggestions.

Comment: @jwvh "someone places an implicit Char in scope" ... _That_ would be dangerous :D Why in the world would you want an implicit char???